# go-gorm query a manytomany field

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have the following models:

```golang
type User struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();primary_key" json:"id"`
    ...
}

type Environment struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();primary_key" json:"id"`
    UserId    uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid" json:"userId"`
    User      User      `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId;references:ID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"-"`
    ...
}

type Secret struct {
    ID           uuid.UUID     `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4();primary_key" json:"id"`
    UserId       uuid.UUID     `gorm:"type:uuid" json:"userId"`
    User         User          `gorm:"foreignKey:UserId;references:ID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"-"`
    Environments []Environment `gorm:"many2many:environment_secrets;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"environments"`
    ...
}
```

When creating a secret that has one or many environments, an `environment_secrets` table creates one or many individual rows depending on how many environments share the same secret:

```
secret_id | environment_id
--------------------------
uuid      | uuid
```

What I'm trying to do is query the `environments` field within the `secrets` table.

The problem I'm running into is that while `Preload` inserts data into the `environments` field, it doesn't appear to be available during the `Find` clause:

```golang
var secrets []models.Secret
if err := db.Preload("Environments").Find(&secrets, "user_id=? AND ? @> environments.id", userSessionId, environmentId).Error; err != nil {
  return c.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(
    fiber.Map{"error": err.Error()},
  )
}
// ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "environments" (SQLSTATE 42P01)
```

In short, I'm trying to write this query: `Within the "secrets" table, look for a matching userId that owns these secrets, and look through the associated "environments.id" field within the secrets for UUIDs that match a specific environment UUID (it'll also owned by this user)`.

For example, if I query `secrets` with this `92a4c405-f4f7-44d9-92df-76bd8a9ac3a6` user UUID to check for ownership, and also query with this `cff8d599-3822-474d-a980-fb054fb923cc` environment UUID, then the resulting output should look something like...

```json
[
    {
        "id": "63f3e041-f6d9-4334-95b4-d850465a588a",
        "userId": "92a4c405-f4f7-44d9-92df-76bd8a9ac3a6", // field to determine ownership by specific user
        "environments": [
            {
                "id": "cff8d599-3822-474d-a980-fb054fb923cc", // field to determine a matching environment UUID
                "userId": "92a4c405-f4f7-44d9-92df-76bd8a9ac3a6", // owned by same user
                "name": "test1",
                "createdAt": "2023-08-24T09:27:14.065237-07:00",
                "updatedAt": "2023-08-24T09:27:14.065237-07:00"
            },
            {
                "id": "65e30501-3bc9-4fbc-8b87-2f4aa57b461f", // this secret happens to also be shared with another environment, however this data should also be included in the results
                "userId": "92a4c405-f4f7-44d9-92df-76bd8a9ac3a6", // owned by same user
                "name": "test2",
                "createdAt": "2023-08-24T12:50:38.73195-07:00",
                "updatedAt": "2023-08-24T12:50:38.73195-07:00"
            }
        ],
        "key": "BAZINGA",
        "value": "JDJhJDEwJHR5VjRWZ3l2VjZIbXJoblhIMU1D",
        "createdAt": "2023-08-24T12:51:05.999483-07:00",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-24T12:51:05.999483-07:00"
    }
    ...etc
]
```

Is there a JOIN query or perhaps a raw SQL query I can write to have the `environments` row data available within `secrets` for a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty, but this raw dog GORM SQL query works as expected:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        s.id,
        s.user_id,
        s.key,
        s.value,
        s.created_at,
        s.updated_at,
        jsonb_agg(envs) as environments
    FROM secrets s
    JOIN environment_secrets es ON s.id = es.secret_id
    JOIN environments envs on es.environment_id = envs.id
    WHERE s.user_id = ?
    GROUP BY s.id
) r
WHERE r.environments @> ?;
```

The query can be read as...

Aggregate secrets as `r` (results) with an `environments` field that has:

- a secret id that matches the manytomany table secret id
- a manytomany table environment id that matches an environment id
- and filter against the secret user id which matches a parameter user id

From the `r` (results) look for a partial parameterized `id` within the `environments` JSON array.

And some sample go code using [gofiber](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber):

```golang
import (
    "time"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "gorm.io/datatypes"
)

type SecretResult struct {
    ID           uuid.UUID      `json:"id"`
    UserId       uuid.UUID      `json:"userId"`
    Environments datatypes.JSON `json:"environments"`
    Key          string         `json:"key"`
    Value        []byte         `json:"value"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time      `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time      `json:"updatedAt"`
}

func Example(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    db := database.ConnectToDB();
    userSessionId := c.Locals("userSessionId").(uuid.UUID)

    parsedEnvId, err := uuid.Parse(c.Params("id"))
    if err != nil {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest).JSON(
            fiber.Map{"error": "You must provide a valid environment id!"},
        )
    }

    var secrets []SecretResult
    if err := db.Raw(`
       USE SQL QUERY MENTIONED ABOVE
    `, userSessionId,`[{"id":"`+parsedEnvId.String()+`"}]`),
    ).Scan(&secrets).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to load secrets with %s: %s", parsedEnvId, err.Error())
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).JSON(
            fiber.Map{"error": "Failed to locate any secrets with that id."},
        )
    }

    return c.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(secrets)
}
```